# Sockect for udp connection in android

Tags: android, sockets, udp, android-wifi

Can anyone tell me which port is used for udp connection in android?
And how to open sockect for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

socket.setSoTimeout        (0);
socket.setSendBufferSize   (16384);
socket.setReceiveBufferSize(16384);

socket.connect(address);
```

is one way of doing it. The socket.setXXX stuff is (obviously) optional.

As far as I remember ports below 1024 are reserved for privileged processes (could be wrong about that though).

Comment: Yeah, they're not to be used.